# Left side menu /partial view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, partial-views, menubar

What is the best approach to take to create a page with a right side  that contains details according to selected menuitem on the left side.

We put the leftside in a partialview or directly in a menu ? (the right side will be partialview that the content will change

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the leftside is used for all pages then you can create it in `_Layout` page, but it is better to use it as `partialview` as shown on the attached image below:

[image]